# Let $f\in C(\Bbb R)$ bounded and partition $\text{Im}(f)=I_1\cup\cdots\cup I_n$ into intervals. When is $f^{-1}(I_k)$ a union of intervals?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f\in C(\Bbb R)$ be bounded, onto, let $I=\text{Im}(f)$, and let $I_1\cup I_2\cup\cdots\cup I_n$ be a partition of $I$. Under what conditions is $f^{-1}(I_k)=\{x\in\Bbb R:f(x)\in I_k\}$ a union of countably many intervals?

I know that if $f$ is monotone then $f^{-1}(I_k)$ must be an interval.

---

For example, define $f(x)=e^{-x}\sin(x)$ (damped oscillation).

Let $I=\text{Im}(f)$ into $I^+=\{x\in I:x\geq 0\}$ and $I^-=\{x\in I:x<0\}$. Then

$$ f^{-1}(I^+) = [0,\pi]\cup[2\pi,3\pi]\cup\cdots$$
$$ f^{-1}(I^-) = (\pi,2\pi)\cup(3\pi,4\pi)\cup\cdots$$

This is good, this is the form I want. Is it enough to restrict that $f$ is continuous?

Comment: Is $f : \mathbb R\to [a,b]$ supposed to be surjective? In the title you write $Im(f)$.

Comment: @amsmath Yes, it is assumed $[a,b]$ is the codomain of $f$.

Comment: Assume that an interval is $I_k = [0,\beta)$ and $a < 0$. Let $f : [c,d]\to [a,0]$ be a function with uncountably many zeros and extend $f$ to $\mathbb R\setminus [c,d]$ such that $(0,b]$ is in the image of $f$. Then $f^{-1}(I_k) = f^{-1}((0,\beta))\cup f^{-1}(\{0\})$, but uncountably many points in $f^{-1}(\{0\})$ aren't boundary points of $f^{-1}((0,\beta))$.

Comment: M. Nestor, the codomain is not the same as the image, in general. So, you did not answer my question.

Comment: @amsmath Yes, assume $f$ is surjective.

Answer (score 1):

No, the inverse image of an interval can have uncountably many components even if $f$ is continuous.  For instance, let $K$ be the Cantor set and let $f(x)=\min(d(x,K),1)$, which we can consider as a continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}\to[-1,1]$.  Then $f^{-1}([-1,0])=K$ has uncountably many connected components.  If you want to require $f$ to be surjective, you can modify it to also go down to $-1$ briefly on some interval far away from $K$, so that $f^{-1}([-1,0])$ is $K$ together with some interval and again has uncountably many connected components.

If you assume $f$ is real-analytic, then that would suffice, since then the zeroes of $f'$ must be isolated (unless $f$ is constant) and so we can split $\mathbb{R}$ into countably many intervals (ordered discretely) on which $f$ is monotone, from which it follows easily that the inverse image of any interval is a countable union of intervals.

Comment: Note that the $I_k$ must be contained in the image of $f$. In your example, this would be $\{0\}$. Now, it depends on whether singletons count as intervals or not. I guess not because $I_1\cup\ldots\cup I_n$ is supposed to be a partition.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "the zeroes of $f'$ must be isolated"?

Comment: @amsmath: The question doesn't say anything about $f$ being surjective.  In any case the example is trivial to modify so that it also goes down to $-1$ on some interval.

Comment: @M.Nestor: If $f$ is real-analytic then so is $f'$, and if the zeroes of a real-analytic function are not isolated then the function must be identically zero.  This follows from the [identity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem) after extending the function analytically to a neighborhood in $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @EricWofsey "The question doesn't say anything about f being surjective." Yes, it (kind of) does. See the title. But concerning the simple modification you're right, of course.

Comment: @amsmath: Oh, I didn't notice that the title and body are not the same.  In any case, I've edited the answer to address either version.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't check this answer. I just wanted to make the obvious statement that $f^{-1}(I_k)$ is always a countable union of intervals (including singletons) if there is no $y$ such that $f^{-1}(\{y\})$ is uncountable. As mentioned by Eric Wofsey, non-constant analytic functions satisfy this property.